# UIToolBar unexpectedly registers taps on UIBarButtonItem instances even when tapping at a considerable distance from them

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I wonder if anyone else has noticed this behavior - searching the web or these forums didn't unearth anything for me:

[Update: issue still exists on iPhones (but not iPads) as of iOS 7.0.1]

In an iPhone app on iOS 4.2.1, down to at least 3.2 (in the Simulator), if you
- have a **toolbar** (`UIToolBar` - whether explicitly created or provided by a `UINavigationController`) filled with `UIBarButtonItem` instances of style `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` (rectangular buttons with rounded borders)
- and you have **considerable empty space between them** (e.g. by using a `UIBarButtonItem` instance of system type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` between two buttons to place one on the far left and the other on the far right)
I observe the following, unexpected behavior:

If you **tap in the empty space** on the toolbar at a **considerable distance from the nearest button**, that button - unexpectedly - still **registers a tap**.

While you could consider that a feature, it can also be disconcerting to users, especially if the tap location does not clearly suggest what function was invoked.
In "thickly settled" views where accidental taps are more likely (e.g. a game whose elements border the toolbar) this behavior increases the likelihood of accidentally invoking functionality.

In my specific case you can tap **up to 56 pixels** to the right of a button and still have it register a tap.

This behavior occurs both in the Simulator and on actual devices.
Has anyone else had this experience? Am I overlooking something?

Thanks for listening/helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how this behavior would be helpful in some cases but unexpected in others.  Please consider filing a bug with Apple at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/.

Answer (score 5):

I also found this to be quite an issue (I have a button positioned directly above a UIToolBar, and I found that most of the time I tried clicking on that button with my thumb, I ended up hitting the empty space in the UIToolbar and activating one of the toolbar buttons instead).

The only way I could find to avoid this issue is by putting a non-functional button between the buttons and the flexible space. That way, any touches inside the flexible space would just activate the non-functional button and nothing would happen. I implemented this with UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView and just used a UIImageView with a 1x1 transparent image (forgive me!):

```
[myToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                 target:nil 
                                                 action:nil] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:
    [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1x1Transparent.png"]] autorelease]] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 1" 
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(button1Pressed:)] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 2" 
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(button2Pressed:)] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 3" 
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(button3Pressed:)] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:
    [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1x1Transparent.png"]] autorelease]] autorelease],
  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                 target:nil 
                                                 action:nil] autorelease], nil]];
```

Comment: That's a clever workaround, thanks. For the long run I've filed a bug with Apple.

Comment: @user1891289's solution simplifies your approach by obviating the need for a transparent image. Another thing to note is that if you have buttons on *both* sides of the `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` button, you need 2 dummy buttons - one on either side.

Answer (score 3):

A smart solution is to simply add a `UIBarButtonItem` instance with plain style and to disable it.

Comment: Nice simplification of @jblust's approach. Specifically, you can create such a button as follows: `[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease]`.